# Turn on autocomplete/hints for code between preprocessor lines

Tags: ide, clion

I have some code wrapped between the following statements:

```
#if POTATO
   (a few lines of c code)
#endif
```

Unfortunately, autocompletion, highlighting, suggestions and everything else stops working for any code between the #if statements. How can I fix this?

Comment: Define `POTATO` in active configuration.